# What means "runtime" in Intel XDK?

Tags: html, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

I am completely new to mobile development and i interested to hybrid apps and of course Intel XDK. When i reading Intel XDK's documentations i faced to "runtime" word.

What is mean of this phrase and actually what is it's mean when they saying

> Crosswalk is a HTML5 runtime, ...

in their [blog post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/blogs/what-is-crosswalk).

Apologize me if I asking one of stackoverflow's stupid questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Runtime" generally refers to the time a program *runs*, as opposed to other times in the programs life cycle like *compile time*. Software is typically written, then compiled, then deployed or installed, then run. These different phases are often referred to as "compile time", "install time" and "runtime". E.g. *"at compile time, the compiler will ..."*.

"*A* runtime" is a software package that is necessary at, well, runtime. E.g. a library, interpreter, virtual machine or other such supporting packages. Crosswalk is a system that takes in HTML 5 "apps" (including HTML, Javascript etc.) and, well, makes them work. Executes them. *Runs* them. It's essentially a browser engine, but not packaged as a browser, just as a system that can interpret and run HTML 5, which you can embed into whatever other software you want.

So you could write your application in HTML 5; then to make that work like a native desktop application which can be downloaded and installed, you write a tiny Windows application and an OS X application which basically just contains Crosswalk, which runs your actual application inside it, cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

**Run-time** - the length of time it takes to execute a software program

The **Intel XDK** includes the Crosswalk runtime as a supported target of the cloud-based build service.

**Crosswalk runtime** can be used for creating HTML5 application with a dedicated runtime that can be run on multiple platforms without any dependency for webview. It can be used for creating application that uses HTML5 features like WebRTC, hardware-accelerated WebGL support and bleeding edge HTML5 features.

For more information please follow this resources..
[crosswalk-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crosswalk-runtime/info)

more resources : [Using the Intel XDK “Crosswalk for Android”](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/using-the-crosswalk-for-android-build-option.html)

Comment: Thanks shuvrow for answering. But I still don't know why the phrase 'runtime' followed by crosswalk. Is it because of running crosswalk in back-end while the application in execution mode?

Comment: In this case, "Crosswalk runtime" refers to the "HTML5 interpreter" that "runs" your HTML5 application. Your HTML5 application is a collection of HTML, CSS and JavaScript files. This is analogous to an HTML5 web app that runs inside of a browser. In that case, the web app "runs" on top of the "browser runtime." So as @deceze indicated, Crosswalk is an embedded browser. When you build an app using the XDK's Crosswalk build option, it includes a full copy of Crosswalk, which "interprets" your HTML5 application.